# Как скачать картинку через python, не зная её адреса

Tags: python

Есть сайт, на нем есть картинки, можно ли скачать картинку без её url? Если попытаться открыть картину по адресу через контекстное меню, то она откроется, но если копировать её адрес выдаст 403 ошибку.

Comment: по всей видимости это CORS https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: самый простой способ - сохранить страницу она сохранится с картинками